# mercurial extensions: efficient templatekeyword implementation

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

I'm writing a mercurial extension, but am finding that template rendering is rather slow.

I was originally using [`cmdutil.rendertemplate()`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/default/mercurial/cmdutil.py#l929), however, it seems that has to reparse the template string every time, which is rather slow.

When switching to the ["new" api for `@templatekeyword`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/default/mercurial/registrar.py#l291), it looks like the first arg passed is a [`mercurial.templater.engine`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/default/mercurial/templater.py#l580) object, which has an `expand` method that caches the parsed versions of templates, which makes it much faster. Unfortunately, [it doesn't expand aliases](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/default/mercurial/templater.py#l701).

Does anyone know the Right Way to efficiently render templates and aliases for a mercurial extension? Right now, the only option I see is copy/pasting the portions of `cmdutil.rendertemplate` and keeping my own global cache...but that feels pretty icky.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you need to

- render a user template loaded from somewhere other than the `[templates]` section,
- in a keyword function,

the current way is to put the loaded template to `templater.cache[name]` first [1], and render it by `context.process(name, mapping)` [2].

1. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/4.7.1/mercurial/cmdutil.py#l2643
2. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/4.7.1/mercurial/templatekw.py#l474

I'm not sure if that's the case you're facing. There
might be a better way depending on context.